# Populating Arrays With Nested Loops in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, nested-loops

I'm curious as to why the following:

```
array1=(file1 file2 file3)
array2=()
for i in ${array1[@]}
do
    find . -name $i -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | \
        while read -d '' -r file
        do
            array2+=( $file )
        done
done
```

fails to populate array2 assuming the filenames file1, file2, and file3 exist in the filesystem in sub-directories from the parent where the search is initiated.  I would appreciate if someone could point out where I mis-stepped here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
array1=(file1 file2 file3)
array2=()
for i in "${array1[@]}"
do
        while read -d '' -r file
        do
            array2+=( "$file" )
        done < <(find . -name "$i" -type f -print0)
done
```

Due to your use of pipes sub shell is created and your array2 values get lost when sub shell ends.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware of how one could re-direct output within nested loops in that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4, you can avoid using `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar
array1=(file1 file2 file3)
array2=()
for i in "${array1[@]}"
do
    for f in **/"$i"; do
        [[ -f "$f" ]] && array2+=( "$f" )
    done
done
```